# Magento MySQL: Too many keys specified; max 64 keys allowed

Tags: php, mysql, magento, key

I'm getting the below error in a `Magento` `PHP` file running a `CREATE TABLE`:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1069 Too many keys specified; max 64 keys allowed
```

The code that triggers it is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('attributesplash_page')} (
    `page_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `option_id` int (11) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
    `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
    `display_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    `short_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    `description` TEXT NOT NULL default '',
    `url_key` varchar(180) NOT NULL default '',
    `page_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    `meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    `meta_keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    `display_mode` varchar(40) NOT NULL default 'PRODUCTS',
    `cms_block` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
    `is_enabled` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`),
    KEY `FK_OPTION_ID_SPLASH_PAGE` (`option_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_OPTION_ID_SPLASH_PAGE` FOREIGN KEY (`option_id`) REFERENCES `{$this->getTable('eav_attribute_option')}` (`option_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    KEY `FK_STORE_ID_SPLASH_PAGE` (`store_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_STORE_ID_SPLASH_PAGE` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `{$this->getTable('core_store')}` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='AttributeSplash: Page';

ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('attributesplash_page')} ADD UNIQUE (option_id, store_id);
```

To me it looks like it's only adding 3 Keys in there. Where are the extras coming from?

Researching the problem has simply turned up the fact that I need to reduce the items that are being used for keys, but I can't see where the extra ones are in the code.

Is there any additional information that would be of use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go through all of your attributes and set whether they are "Used in product listing" to 'no' and "Used for sorting in product listing" to 'no'.

I have not experienced this problem in recent versions of Magento, however, the above worked for me once. I was then able to think again about what attributes I really needed to have on and where.

Comment: I've come across discussions on this being a problem sometimes with upgrading Magento. I just wasn't sure if that would be the case here since it is not a core module. I couldn't decipher the above SQL to work out where the Keys were coming from. Whether it was from attributes, or something to do with the module's tables.

Comment: Did you give it a go? I thought/guessed(!) that you were still on `eav_attribute_option` with your new additions and the 'usual solution' might be worth a try. Anyway, good luck with it, and your module looks ambitious b.t.w.!

Comment: I ended up passing it to the original developer. But your answer seems to be the one suggested for this sort of problem on other boards, so I'm marking accepted. Thanks for the help.